# Using google custom search to find the number of indexed urls

Tags: php, google-api, google-custom-search

I am looking for a good way of finding how many pages from my site are indexed in google.  I have been looking at the google custom search api.  Below is the code they give in the sample documents.

```
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_CustomsearchService.php';
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Internet Report Card');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXX MY KEY');
$search = new Google_CustomsearchService($client);
$result = $search->cse->listCse('site:mysite.com', array(
    'cref' => 'http://www.google.com/???????????',                                                                            
));
print "<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>";
```

I cant seem to figure out what my cref should be or what the code should be in order to pull the correct information.

I have seen the following url code on many sites

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={{Removed API Key}}&q=site:' . $domain
```

I may be wrong but I believe that is the code for the old api.

Comment: If you found it, can you please share the solution here. I am looking for the same. Want to pull the number of google indexed pages. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

You could use ajax search api to get the total count of indexed page:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=YOURSITE.COM
```

Answer (score -2):

That's what Google Webmaster Tools are for. You can read more here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2642366?hl=en

Comment: NO You would think if i knew about google apis I would know what webmaster tools is.  I am trying to convert an old api to a new one for a reason.  Thus the question you completely ignored. We have an automated system with 300 websites